# Installing ruby-ldap gem on windows (using ruby 2.1.6)

Tags: ruby, windows, ldap

I have trouble installing ruby-ldap gem on windows (I have ruby 2.1.6 and have configured devkit to compile extensions) . I get the following error when I tried gem install it throws the following error

```
extconf.rb:197:in ``': Permission denied - lib /def:./win/wldap32.def /out:./win/wldap32.lib (Errno:
:EACCES)
```

I tried installing as Administrator 
I tried adding wldap32.lib file in my win folder

Here is the full log to this issue
    Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing ruby-ldap:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of      necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby21/bin/ruby
        --with-netscape
        --without-netscape
        --without-netscape
        --with-mozilla
        --without-mozilla
        --without-mozilla
        --with-openldap1
        --without-openldap1
        --without-openldap1
        --with-openldap2
        --without-openldap2
        --without-openldap2
        --with-wldap32
        --without-wldap32
        --without-wldap32
        --with-ldap-dir
        --without-ldap-dir
        --with-ldap-include
        --without-ldap-include=${ldap-dir}/include
        --with-ldap-lib
        --without-ldap-lib=${ldap-dir}/lib
        --with-ldap-dir
        --without-ldap-dir
        --without-ldap-dir
        --with-ldap
        --without-ldap
        --without-ldap
extconf.rb:197:in ``': Permission denied - lib /def:./win/wldap32.def /out:./win/wldap32.lib (Errno:
:EACCES)
        from extconf.rb:197:in `<main>'
--with-wldap32

extconf failed, exit code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows isn't officially supported with that gem, from the README

```
PORTS

  * FreeBSD ("Akinori -Aki- MUSHA" <knu@idaemons.org>)
  * Debian (Akira Yamada <akira@ruby-lang.org>)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Also, there is https://github.com/bearded/ruby-ldap/wiki/How-to-compile-ruby-ldap-on-Windows however I don't see that as working with the latest version, and here are some things that would need to be changed in order to support it.

1. it uses `lib`, devkit uses `link`, so it would have to be changed to `link /lib` in extconf.rb, which is what is giving you the permission denied error.
2. there is the loading `time.h` issue so each include for time.h would have to be changed to something like

```
#if HAVE_SYS_TIME_H && !defined(_WIN32)
#include 
#endif
```

3. in extconf.rb should be something like `have_header("sys/time.h") unless win32`
4. and last but not least `conn.c:183: undefined reference to`ldap_initialize'`most likely because something isn't installed, I'm thinking`ldap.h` (read ldap binary)

So, sorry but I think this is a no go.